# bootstrap css not works with window.showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have added following line in my aspx page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Following is my javascript code in default2.aspx

```
window.showModalDialog('default1.aspx');
```

When i resize window its not working.

Its working with

```
window.open('default1.aspx');
```

**NOTE** : default1.aspx page is on another domain.

Comment: which browser and version

Comment: my browser is IE and version is 10

Comment: create a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: Beware that [`showModalDialog` is being permanently removed from Chrome.](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html) You should rework your code to avoid it.